# getting current time in groovy/java

Tags: java, groovy

I have the following code in groovy to get current time in hours.

```
def now = new Date()
  def time = now.getHours()
```

but the getHour() method is deprecated. What are the disadvantages if I use this method and the what is the alternative to this method in groovy/Java ?

Comment: It tells you what to use [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: getMinutes and getHours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907170/java-getminutes-and-gethours)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150155/java-gethours-getminutes-and-getseconds and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343524/the-correct-way-to-set-and-get-hour-minutes-sec

Comment: actually I want to know the disadvantages of using deprecated methods. the only one I know is that latter version of jre will not include them, are there any other disadvantages ?

Comment: It was deprecated for a reason. Usually thread safety, poor design, or just not working correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901262/why-were-most-java-util-date-methods-deprecated

Comment: @sikander I can tell you from experience that those methods in `java.util.Date` have been deprecated for over 10 years now.  I wouldn't be too concerned about them actually being removed. I think they are deprecated because the entire Date class' design ignores all timezone considerations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Calendar`,

```
  Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();//it return same time as new Date()
  def hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
```

For details, read this [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29).

Answer (score 9):

Try using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of standard java.util.Date classes. Joda Time library has much better API for handling dates.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();  // current time
int month = dt.getMonth();     // gets the current month
int hours = dt.getHourOfDay(); // gets hour of day
```

You can use the traditional classes like this to fetch fields from given Date instance.

```
Date date = new Date();   // given date
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
calendar.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);        // gets hour in 12h format
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);       // gets month number, NOTE this is zero based!
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use Joda-time for get current time or getHours